# How do password managers run JS after a page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, pageload

Password managers (PMs) are tools that can accomplish simple login form-filling automatically after loading a page, even one with high security such as for online banking. I want to create my own personal PM in JS that can run more complex site-specific programs, such as handling optional subpasswords and strange multiple-page or multiple-choice logins (such as are used by Google).

How do existing PMs continue to run JS after loading the target page and before the target page itself runs JS? How do they retain control? There must be some non-obvious yet effective trick. Can someone give a brief skeleton of tested code that inserts a username into the login page of some well-known site? Or does this task require mastering the writing of a browser extension/addon?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would have to manually set which fields to save query selectors and values for, and then use this code for the filler:

```
var pmdata=[
    {query:/*query selector here*/,value:/*input value*/},
    {query:/*another query selector here*/,value:/*another input value*/}
];
var passwordMan=setInterval(function(){
    pmdata.forEach(function(e){
        if(document.querySelector(e.query)){
        document.querySelector(e.query).value=e.value;
        pmdata.splice(pmdata.indexOf(e),1);
        }
    });
    if(pmdata.length==0)clearInterval(passwordMan);
},100);
```

Note that this will not work if the inputs are cleared after the values are written into them.